# Calculate OAuth signature for NetSuite restlet using bash

Tags: bash, curl, oauth

I'm currently trying to generate an OAuth signature for my curl request header. These point to a NetSuite restlet. Resources online are either inconclusive or too high level for my understanding/lacking examples. How do I go about calculating the `oauth_signature` value for my request?

The following is my request with credentials ommitted:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url 'https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=foo&deploy=bar' \
  --header 'Authorization: OAuth realm="'"$realm"'",oauth_consumer_key="'"$oauth_consumer_key"'",oauth_token="'"$oauth_token"'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="'"$(OAuth_timestamp)"'",oauth_nonce="'"$(OAuth_nonce)"'",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="'"$(OAuth_signature)"'"' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
 | jq
```

Below is a list of the parameters I'm passing for the sake of readability:

```
params=(
    oauth_consumer_key='foo'
    oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA1'
    oauth_version='1.0'
    oauth_nonce=$(OAuth_nonce)
    oauth_timestamp=$(OAuth_timestamp)
    oauth_token='tokenfoo'
    realm='4478811'
)
```

I am generating the timestamp and nonce like so:

```
OAuth_nonce () {
    md5 <<< "$RANDOM-$(date +%s.%N)" | cut -d' ' -f 1
}

OAuth_timestamp () {
    echo "$(date +%s)"
}
```

I got most of my resources from https://github.com/livibetter-backup/bash-oauth but no docs exist, the examples are poor, and the library itself doesn't seem to work when I've tested the functions.

All the values I use in the script (confirmed passing with `bash +x`) work when ran in Postman, but I can't calculate a `oauth_signature` value outside of it.

How do I create a `OAuth_signature` function that I can return a valid signature with? What parameters am I going to have to pass that function to calculate correctly? Is it possible or easier to generate perhaps using perl or python?

Comment: Can you explain more on `How do I create a OAuth_signature function that I can return a valid signature with?` with some samples

Comment: Also don't use `<<<` with `md5` it creates an extra new line at the end of the string.

Comment: @Inian Informing just incase before explaining: Postman is a GUI client you can use to make HTTP requests. It automatically generates a timestamp, nonce, and signature value for you, than appends them to your Authorization header.

There are almost no sources online explaining how to get the signature, outside of this link: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures which is way too high level for myself.

Comment: @Inian What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: what did you end up doing?